# Calling OpenACC code from Rust does not run on GPU

Tags: rust, openacc, pgi, pgi-accelerator

Update 09/07/2020

I'm adding a small example for this at https://gitlab.com/lisanhu2016/rust-openacc-example.git

It's a public repository with a README, you should be able to try the example there.

The libraries I have been linking to are: nvc, acchost, pgm, you can see them in `build.rs`

===

I’m trying to call openacc code from rust code and I’m having issues probably related to linking.
I’m using the following steps:

1. compiling `bindings.cc` with openacc flags `-acc -gpu=managed -Minfo=accel` and convert it to a static library `libfoo.a`

```
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/bindings.cc.o
/opt/nvidia/hpc/20.7/Linux_x86_64/20.7/compilers/bin/nvc++    -fast -O3 -DNDEBUG   -fPIC -acc -gpu=managed -Minfo=accel -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/bindings.cc.o -c /usa/lisanhu/tmp/rust-c-ffi-example/bindings.cc
process_batch:
      6, Generating copyout(lengths[:array.l]) [if not already present]
         Generating implicit copyin(array.data[:]) [if not already present]
         Generating Tesla code
         10, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
      6, Generating implicit copyin(array) [if not already present]
[100%] Linking CXX static library libfoo.a
```

2. compiling rust code with `libfoo.a`, and dynamically link to libraries `nvc` `nvcpumath` `nvhost` `nvdevice`.
3. run the code with some data, it runs.
4. run the code with `PGI_ACC_TIME=1`, there's no timing info
5. run the code with `ncu --set full`, it shows no kernel information

I think we probably are linking to the wrong libraries but I'm not sure, would you please help me with this problem? Thank you so much!!

Comment: my suggestion to make it easier for others to help you would be to provide a complete example.  All the files needed to reproduce your observation.  A [mcve].  Include whatever is needed from both rust and OpenACC.  Providing your CMakefile files also is probably a good idea.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you for your advice! I've created a public repository containing a small example with a README describing how to reproduce the problem. Really appreciate it if you would like to take a look at it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with Sanhu via the OpenACC Slack channel on this one.  There were two issues.

First since he's not linking with PGI/NV, he needs to add the "-gpu=nordc" flag.  RDC requires a device link step not performed when being linked by Rust.

Second, since the "data" array is being allocated by Rust, it wont be put into CUDA Unified Memory.  Hence he needed to add it to an OpenACC data region with the "process_array" routine.

Comment: Thank you so much Mat! Some points for this to work: 1. Find the libraries using -dryrun on nvhpc compiler, 2. make sure to link those libraries and try not to use managed memory, 3. the library should be compiled using nordc